# Thymeleaf returns Null field with ModelAndView binding

Tags: spring-boot, post, thymeleaf

So, i had this same code working earlier and i do not get why it suddenly stopped working.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/PostOptions}" th:object="${Obj}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" th:field="*{id}" />
            <td ><input id="viewable" type="text" name="param" th:field="*{param}" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Search brackets" /></td>
        </form>
```

An simple object for retrieving search params for next phase

```
@Entity
public class SearchParam {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
long id;

private String param;

//Getter & setter & contructor (empty and with param attributes)
```

And here i bind the object on GET

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "makeOptions")
public ModelAndView makeOptions() {

    SearchParam searchParam = new SearchParam();

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new   ModelAndView("returnPage");
    modelAndView.addObject("Obj", searchParam);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

And then try to read it on POST

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "PostOptions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postOptions(@ModelAttribute(value = "Obj") @Validated SearchParam param) {

    System.out.println(param.getParam() );
   //method has other stuff too
```

but now i only get null on print.

What am i missing this time?
How can i effectively debug this thing?

Comment: Add your getter and setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java won this round...

Only solution after hours of looking was to revert back to last commit...
Admins may Close / Delete the question, thanks